# Python Pandas: Index of a matching value within the same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of a few thousand rows. There is a column where each value in that column appears exactly twice. I want to locate the index of each matching value. The column looks like so:

```
  col
1 cat
2 dog 
3 bird
4 dog
5 bird
6 cat
```

And I would like to know the corresponding index where the match appears so it would return something like this:

```
[1] 6 4 5 2 3 1
```

Comment: Can you explain your output ?

Comment: @BENY
The matching index for row 1 is 6
The matching index for row 2 is 4
The matching index for row 3 is 5
And so on
Sorry for the bad formatting!

Answer (score 1):

Group by the values in `col`, and use [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to shift group indices by 1 :

(the last index comes to front)

```py
s = df['col']
s.groupby(s).transform(lambda x: np.roll(x.index, 1))
```

**Result:**

```py
1    6
2    4
3    5
4    2
5    3
6    1
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get a list of all the index's for each word in col

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['col'])['index'].apply(list).reset_index(name='matching_index')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Car','Bike','Truck','Car','Airplane'])
df.columns = ["Something"]
duplicateRows = df[df.duplicated()] # Just this line makes the magic =)
duplicateRows
```

The Output:

```
    Something
3         Car
```

To consider:

`df[df.duplicated()]` Find Duplicate Rows Across All Columns, if you want to keep the last value, you can use `df[df.duplicated(keep='last')]`. And if you need find duplicates in a specific columns, you can use: `df[df.duplicated(['column1', 'column2'])]`